# CSV value in pivot query

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, pivot

here is my table

```
Manger  EmpID
ABC     5
ABC     6
XYZ     2
XYZ     3
```

if i  use pivot query i am getting below output.

```
 ABC    XYZ
 6      3
```

**But actually i want such output.**

```
  ABC   XYZ
  5,6   2,3
```

I dont' want aggregate value, i want csv values.
can anyone please help me to get such output.
here is my sql code

```
    Select * 
INTO #TEMP
FROM 
(SELECT 'ABC' As Manger , 5 as EmpID
union
SELECT 'ABC' As Manger , 6 as EmpID
union
SELECT 'XYZ' As Manger , 2 as EmpID
union
SELECT 'XYZ' As Manger , 3 as EmpID
) A

select * 
FROM #TEMP



select * 
FROM #TEMP
PIVOT
(
    MAX([EmpID])
    FOR Manger IN ([ABC],[XYZ])
) as P

drop table #TEMP
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
   SELECT DISTINCT Manager, 
          STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(EmpID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS [text()]
                 FROM #TEMP AS t2
                 WHERE t1.Manager = t2.Manager
                 FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '') AS EmpID
   FROM #TEMP AS t1) AS SRC       
PIVOT
(
    MAX([EmpID])
    FOR Manager IN ([ABC],[XYZ])
) as P
```

The trick is to pre-process your table before applying `PIVOT`. The above query uses [`FOR XML PATH`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510462.aspx) to create a comma separated list of `EmpID` values for each `Manager`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/a1dae2/2)

Comment: Thanks giorgos for this solution